# Estimates in Lp and Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Given $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))\cap L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and $v\in H^1([0,T]\times \Omega) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$, can one conclude $u \cdot\nabla v \in L^2([0,T]\times \Omega)$?

Some proof i read seems to use this but i think this is wrong? The best i can see is $u \cdot \nabla v \in L^1([0,T] \times \Omega )$, since $u, \nabla v \in L^2.$

Also one could show $u \in L^4,$ but again this is not enough.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: What's the dimension of $\Omega$?  (i.e is $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{1}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, etc.)

Comment: We have $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions on $v$ imply $\nabla v\in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. 
But $u$ is at best in $L^4(0,T;L^4(\Omega))$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$. Hence, it holds $u\cdot \nabla v \in L^{4/3}(0,T;L^{4/3}(\Omega))$ at best, 
$u\cdot \nabla v$ is *not* in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ in general.

Comment: How do you get this regularity of $v$? It does not follow from $v \in H^1([0,T] \times \Omega) = H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$.

Comment: Must have misread the question, edited.

Comment: In the proof i read we have to show $\int _{[0,T]\times\Omega} (u_n - u)u\nabla v \rightarrow 0$, where $u$ is the strong limit of $u_n$ in $L^2$ and $u_n$ bounded in the same spaces as $u$. 

Am i right to say, that by what you said this convergence follows (at least for a subsequence) because of duality between $L^4(0,T;L^4)$ and $L^\frac{4}{3}(0,T;L^\frac{4}{3})$?